# Erlang regular expressions - html + em dash and en dash

Tags: html, regex, erlang

Given the string: "...young girl --- eight? nine? ten? --- came dancing...", I would like to return in my browser actual em dashes, e.g., long dashes.

But when I enter this code in Erlang source to generate the string in html:

Clip1 = re:replace(Clip, "---", "\—", [global, {return, binary}]),

I get this in my browser:

"young girl — eight? nine? ten? — came dancing"

Same thing if I enter "\&#8212" for the em dash.

In other words,  the character code is returned rather than the character that I'm hoping to see.

If I don't escape the & in the character code I get this:

young girl ---mdash; eight? nine? ten? ---mdash;

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: did you try this in replacement? io:format("~c", [151])

Comment: If I understand your suggestion, Cowboy crashes when I use Clip1 = re:replace(Clip, "---", io:format("~c", [151]), [global, {return, binary}]) into my Erlang code.

Comment: In your question it looks like you are actually getting the em dash.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this, but it does come up as an em dash in the question, but not in my browser. The difference, I think, is that in my browser I'm generating the text through re:replace/4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the problem! I had failed to add...

```
<meta charset=\"utf-8\">
```

...to the head section of the html that I was returning to the browser. Once done, the em dash and en dash displayed just fine.

Many many thanks to the generous folks who took time to help me solve the problem. rvirding pointed out an error in my unicode formulation, which addressed one issue; fenolp steered me to a nice binary replace function that I can now add to my bag of tricks.

The deeper issue is this: I've been trying to re-purpose an Erlang Cowboy REST (rest_pastebin) example without fully understanding what I'm doing. When I compared my re-purposed code with another REST example (rest_hello_world), however, I spotted the problem. So another big thank you goes to the folks who wrote the Cowboy examples. I can't stress how important well-conceived example code is to those of us trying to master Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems here:

- When you write a string literal then the `\` character is a quote character which works together with the following character in the string literal. As quoting `&` has no special meaning then the `&` is returned as is. So the string `"\&#8212"` becomes just `"&#8212"`. An `&` in the replacement string is replaced with characters which the pattern matched. So to get an `&` in the string you would need to write `"\\&#8212"`.
- You cannot have a character > 255 in the strings. If you want a larger character then it needs to be UTF-8 encoded. Doing something like `<<8212/utf8>>` will create a binary with a UTF-8 encoded em dash. This is a limitation of the `re` module and not of having strings as lists, normally using strings as lists allows you to use the Unicode codepoint directly with encoding.

**EDIT**

- Just saw you can have unencoded unicode characters in list string with `re` if you use the option `unicode`. So:

  ```
  21> re:replace(C, "---", [8212], [global,unicode,{return,list}]).
  [46,46,46,121,111,117,110,103,32,103,105,114,108,32,8212,32,
   101,105,103,104,116,63,32,110,105,110,101,63,32|...]
  ```

  To get the result as a UTF-8 encode binary then you can do:

  ```
  22> re:replace(C, "---", <<8212/utf8>>, [global,unicode,{return,binary}]).
  <<46,46,46,121,111,117,110,103,32,103,105,114,108,32,226,
    128,148,32,101,105,103,104,116,63,32,110,105,110,101,...>>
  ```

Comment: If I enter the character code directly into a paragraph as html source, it shows up correctly as an em dash in my browser. But if I accept text through a textarea and process it through this line of code to generate html code it fails: Clip1 = re:replace(Clip, "---", "\\&#151", [global, {return, binary}]). This code works correctly, however: ClipID = re:replace(Panel, " ", "_", [global, {return, binary}]).

Comment: I get the same result as Robert above if I run re:replace/4 in the Erlang shell. If I run it in my application, this is saved to file and read in Vim: <P>em dash: — en dash: –^M</P>
  and this when read from file and displayed directly to browser: em dash: â€” en dash: â€“.

Comment: Here's the html being sent to browser: format_html(Clip, plain) -> Text = escape_html_chars(read_file(Clip)),<<"<!DOCTYPE html><html>", "<head><title>tagged text</title></head>", <body>&#8212; &#8211;<br>",Text/binary, "</body></html>\n">>. Note that the character code in html displays just fine; but when Clip is read from file and displayed in format_html/1, it displays as: em dash: â€” en dash â€“

Comment: The only character being escaped in escape_html_chars/1 is "<"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regexp for that.

```
binary:replace(Clip, <<"---">>, <<8212/utf8>>, [global]).
```

http://erldocs.com/R16B03/stdlib/binary.html?i=26&search=binary:#replace/3

Comment: Thanks, fenolp. Nice function. Wasn't aware of it. But it still doesn't solve the mystery. I'm going to sleep on it, then systematically review the evidence and do some more experimentation. The failure occurs somewhere in the save-to-disk/read-from-disk/display leg. Works fine in the substitute/display leg.